# How can I render a semTable to docx format in Quarto?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, docx, quarto

I am trying to include the results of some structural equation models using lavaan in a quarto document. I need to render to docx format so that colleagues who don't use quarto or rmarkdown can edit it.

I'm using the semTable package to produce formatted results. This all works fine when rendering to pdf. But the tables aren't appearing in the docx file.

I found that adding `filters: parse-latex` to the YAML makes it so that latex code gets read as such. And semTable is returning latex code. But I can't get quarto to recognize it. (Btw, I don't know if its necessary for the `parse-latex` option, but I downloaded Parse LaTeX - a Lua filter from https://github.com/tarleb/parse-latex, with `quarto install extension tarleb/parse-latex` beforehand.)

Here is a minimal working example that should work in a fresh quarto document (assuming the Parse LaTeX - a Lua filter Package isn't necessary):

````
---
title: "Minimal working example"
format: docx
filters: 
  - parse-latex
execute: 
  echo: true
---

If I do this I get a latex table: 

```{=latex}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\caption{A Table}
\end{table}
```

This code produces input for a latex table

```{r}
library(tibble)
library(lavaan)
library(semTable)

df <- tibble(x = rnorm(100),
             y = 0.5 * x + rnorm(100))

m1 <- "y ~ x"
m1.fit <- lavaan::sem(m1, data = df)

semTable::semTable(m1.fit, type = "latex")
```

But I can't pass it to a latex chunk to be parsed: 

```{=latex}
semTable::semTable(m1.fit, type = "latex")
```
````

How can I take the results and get Quarto to recognize it as latex code so that I can pack it into a `{=latex}` chunk?

Also might be important: I tried using `#| output: asis` but that isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that docx cannot transform all latex code that gets produced by the function. Using `results='asis'` is in theory perfectly right. You could use `kableExtra` instead that works better in Docx, e.g.

````
```{r results='asis'}
lavaan::sem(m1, data = df) |> broom::tidy() |> kableExtra::kbl(format = "latex")
```
````

Compare the code produced by semtable:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}r*{4}{S[
                         input-symbols = ( ) +,
                         group-digits = false,
                         table-number-alignment = center,
                         %table-space-text-pre = (,
                         table-align-text-pre = false,
                         table-align-text-post = false,
                         table-space-text-post = {***},
                         parse-units = false]}@{}}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Model}\tabularnewline \hline
```

vs. the one produced by kableExtra:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
\hline
term & op & estimate & std.error & statistic & p.value & std.lv & std.all & std.nox\\
\hline
y \textasciitilde{} x & \textasciitilde{} & 0.4697298 & 0.1110110 & 4.231382 & 2.32e-05 & 0.4697298 & 0.3896878 & 0.3934721\\
\hline
y \textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{} y & \textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{} & 1.2087534 & 0.1709435 & 7.071068 & 0.00e+00 & 1.2087534 & 0.8481434 & 0.8481434\\
\hline
x \textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{} x & \textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{} & 0.9808574 & 0.0000000 & NA & NA & 0.9808574 & 1.0000000 & 0.9808574\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that does work. I don't know if I have enough control with kableExtra though, I might have to make the table by hand after all...